# Why does Swift let me call setTitle on AnyObject?

Tags: cocoa, swift

```
@IBAction func helloClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    sender.setTitle("Click", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

The above code works fine. But `setTitle` isn't a method on `AnyObject`? Shouldn't this be a compile time error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of the language specification (see the section on [id compatibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html))

> You can also call any Objective-C method and access any property (On AnyObject) without casting to a more specific class type.

This is to allow for easier Objective-C interop.

The guide also states the following:

> However, because the specific type of an object typed as AnyObject is not known until runtime, it is possible to inadvertently write unsafe code.

Obviously as the validity of your code is only determined at runtime, this can be unsafe.

Comment: The compiler does know that 'setTitle2' for example does not exist and it won't compile it. So it won't let me write unsafe code.

Comment: Of course it will let you write unsafe code.  It will let you write `(NSArray() as AnyObject).setTitle("foo", forState:.Normal)` which will almost certainly crash.  Likewise, given your example code, it would let you call `helloClick(NSArray())` which would have a similar effect.  Any time you use AnyObject it's unsafe, unless you always first insure that the your proposed operation is safe.  Usually by appropriately typecasting it to something more specific.

Comment: @IanWarburton: You can call any method name where there was an `@objc` method declaration with that name visible to the compiler. You imported an API with the method name `setTitle:`, but it has never seen any class with a method name `setTitle2:`. If you declared a class with an `@objc` method with name `setTitle2:`, then yes, it would compile it.

Answer (score 3):

`AnyObject` behaves similarly to Objective-C's `id`

It allows any method to be called on it. The purpose of `AnyObject` *is* to bypass compile time errors. You can call any method on an `AnyObject` and it will compile fine. You will only see errors in runtime.

Per the docs,

> You can also call any Objective-C method and access any property (On AnyObject) without casting to a more specific class type.